# ClassNotFoundException when running Grails AWS Plugin

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the Grails AWS Plugin: https://github.com/grails-aws/grails-aws on Grails 2.2.2.  I can't get the basic S3 File upload to work.  I receive the error below:

Error Log:

```
ERROR (SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:225) - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception [org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/params/SyncBasicHttpParams] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jets3t.service.utils.RestUtils.createDefaultHttpParams(RestUtils.java:574)
    at org.jets3t.service.utils.RestUtils.initHttpConnection(RestUtils.java:298)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.initHttpConnection(RestStorageService.java:209)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.initializeDefaults(RestStorageService.java:166)
    at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.<init>(StorageService.java:125)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.<init>(RestStorageService.java:153)
    at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.<init>(S3Service.java:91)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.<init>(RestS3Service.java:157)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.<init>(RestS3Service.java:131)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.<init>(RestS3Service.java:109)
    at grails.plugin.aws.s3.S3FileUpload.inputStreamUpload(S3FileUpload.groovy:85)
    at grails.plugin.aws.util.MetaClassInjector$_injectS3UploadMethods_closure3.doCall(MetaClassInjector.groovy:46)
```

Here is the BuildConfig:

```
compile ":aws:1.6.7.5"
```

Controller:

```
file.inputStream.s3upload(newFilename) {
   path "pictures/"
}
```

So there's nothing special going on here, just basic configuration, but it doesn't work.  Any ideas?

UDPATE:

Ran the dependency report to make sure the app is using HTTPClient 4.2 and it is:

```
httpclient by org.apache.httpcomponents 4.2 4.1.2
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a default bucket specified? The closure data used above does not have one specified.

Comment: @dmahapatro yes, I have a default bucket specified in Config.groovy

Comment: Based on your comment to the answer, it looks like HTTPClient dependency is clashing, because the [plugin brings in the same dependency](https://github.com/grails-aws/grails-aws/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy#L24). Can you run a `grails dependency-report` and see if that particular artifact is being compromised?

Answer (score 2):

The the Grails AWS plugin uses AWS SDK 1.6.7 which is dependent on Apache HttpClient 4.2 as you can tell from [Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.6.7).

Please add the following dependency to your `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```groovy
runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2'
```

Comment: actually, the app is using HTTPClient 4.2 based on what I see in the dependency report. Even with your recommendation the error persists. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get it to work by adding the following to the *BuildConfig.groovy*:

```
build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2'
build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2'
runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2'
runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2'
```